# function undefined that should be there?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object of type "user" that should have a function "getPermission()". During runtime (of Angular 7) it throws the error "TypeError: this.user.getPermission is not a function".

Here ist what seems to me to be the essential context:

My user class:

```
export class User  {
   ...
   public getPermission(): boolean {
      return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

I have a service from which I fetch a user from the api (which is asp.net core):

```
 getUser(id): Observable<User> {
   return this.http.get<User>(this.baseurl + 'user/' + id);
 }
```

then I have a resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEditResolver implements Resolve<User> {
   constructor(private userService: UserService, private authService: AuthService,
       private router: Router,
       private alertify: AlertifyService) {}

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User> {
       return this.userService.getUser(this.authService.decodedToken.nameid).pipe(
           catchError(error => {
               this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving your data');
               this.router.navigate(['/users']);
               return of(null);
           })
       );
   }
}
```

and finally in my component I call the function getPermission:

```
 user: User;

 ngOnInit() {

   this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
     this.user = data['user'];
   });

   const t: boolean = this.user.getPermission();
 }
```

And as written above, I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.user.getPermission is not a function
```

Beside the function and all other functions which are not present at runtime, all properties loaded from the api are there.

I would be so thankful for any hit how this could happen !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript only exists in compile time. It does not do anything in runtime.

Simply doing `this.http.get<User>(...)` will not convert anything you received to the class `User` you specify.

You need to parse the input yourself and instantiates the `User` instance.

Comment: Hi unional, I tried to understand what you mean, but ... why <User> does not parse the response ? And where should I do this to instantiate User instances? Thanks a lot for some more help !

Comment: When you **cast** the response to a User, the User class is not instantiated. TypeScript only decorates its type system on top of JavaScript. All type information is removed when compiling to JavaScript. No magic is done. You need to `new User()` and fill in the properties from the response yourself.

Comment: Hi unional, thank for your help. I found the class-transformer and this works fine ! https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer
If you have any suggestion if there is something better out there, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

create an instance of the class

```
user: User = new User();
```

Comment: I tried this (in the component) but still have the same result !
Do you mean this ?

user: User = new User();

 ngOnInit() {

   this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
     this.user = data['user'];
   });

   const t: boolean = this.user.getPermission();
 }